# How to document a REST C ++ API automatically?

Tags: c++, swagger, api-doc

I have a REST API in C ++, ready and working correctly. It is not simple, with many files (.hpp, .cpp, .h etc.) plus many libraries and dependencies. However, I would like to know if there is any way to do the automatic documentation of this API, so that the new features added will also be documented automatically.

As a result of my research, the solution would be to use the Oat++ (oatpp) template, as in this example (available on [this Medium post](https://medium.com/oatpp/c-oatpp-web-service-with-swagger-ui-and-auto-documented-endpoints-1d4bb7b82c21)), but for that I should modify the existing code, which I don't want to do (since I am not the author). Has anyone been through something similar and could help me?

Comment: You can try https://swagger.io/

Comment: Nothing is documented "automatically" - *someone* has to actually *write* meaningful documentation text *somewhere*.

Comment: Even if not automatically, is there any way to document without modifying the current code?

Comment: @PaulinellyOliveira I find that well separated and well explained markdown files are nice.

Comment: You can get skeleton swagger docs from the endpoint configuration if your chosen web framework supports it. What web server is your existing code currently using? (but I agree with @GuillaumeRacicot 's point. After a certain level of complexity, quality hand-written documentation is a must)

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at this tool, [apiDoc](https://apidocjs.com/#getting-started).
To generate, simply run

```
apidoc -o . -i . -f *.hpp
```